# How to do support loops to combine smooth, curved surface with hard edge

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

So time and time again I come across a problem with shapes like that one below, where the smooth faces are ment to keep the curvature but the extruded bits shoud have sharp edges and blend seamlessly at the top last face with to curvature.
[image: Pure topology]

But I'm unable to route the support loops in a way that would gime me a clean surface without pinching
Below are few of my failed attempts at this:
[image]
[image]

Using Bewel weight:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You simply could model the surface and the details as different, not connected parts of the same mesh.

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=SGNxAorx" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/SGNxAorx/)

Comment: AFE-GmdG I think it defeats the whole purpose of subd modeling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topology works:

[image]

[image]

Same with 3 edge loops:

[image]

if you need a sharp horizontal edge:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess the first photo is the best , but its missing the support loops on the flat face. Then again the second photo has that sharper horizontal edge that Im not looking for

Comment: I've edited, please tell me if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but honestly your method you added works better then it looks from topology(with that triangle which everybody tells me are basically worse then hell). Many thanks man!

Comment: yes sometimes don't hesitate to use tris   ;)